# SQL join, get data from one table

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, join

I have a question about joins. How to get all Order of Customer with a specified name.

In my result I want only have all columns from "Orders" table and zero columns from "Customers" table. Here you can see tables: 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID
WHERE CustomerName = "Wilman Kala"
```

I tested this here: 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join 
It returns all columns from two tables.

Thanks in advance for a help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the table name before the `*`.

```
SELECT orders.*
FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID
WHERE CustomerName = "Wilman Kala"
```

Or better name every single column you want to select

```
select orders.col1, orders.col2, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT O.*
FROM Orders O
LEFT JOIN Customers C ON O.CustomerID=C.CustomerID
WHERE C.CustomerName = 'Wilman Kala'
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I have to small amount of points to vote up

Answer (score 1):

If you only want columns from `Orders`, you might consider `IN` or `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM Orders o
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Customers c
              WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID AND
                    c.CustomerName = 'Wilman Kala'
             );
```

This does something slightly different from the `JOIN` version.  If two customers have the same name, this will return each order only once.  In a version with `JOIN`, the orders will be duplicated if the names are duplicated.

Usually, the non-duplication behavior is what you want.

Comment: Why not `... WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID ...)`?

Comment: @CL. . . . You can do that.  Because `NOT EXISTS` is preferable to `NOT IN` semantically (the difference in how they handle `NULL`s), I tend to stick with `EXISTS` over `IN`.